# How to get values from dynamically generated DOM input elements Java

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

so I have this HTML code:

```
<form method="get" action="#" id="startForm">
    <input type="text" name="period" id="period" placeholder="The number of days"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="startSubmit"/>
</form>
```

and this is the JavaScript code:

```
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('startSubmit');
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var myForm = document.createElement('form');
    var period  = document.getElementById('period').value;

    for(var i = 0; i < period ; i++){

        var input0 = document.createElement('input');   

        input0.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input0.setAttribute('placeholder', 'The count of tasks');
        input0.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 10px');
        input0.setAttribute('id', 'taskDone'+i);
        input0.setAttribute('onchange', 'myFunction()');

        document.body.appendChild(input0);
        myForm.appendChild(input0);
        document.body.appendChild(myForm);

        function myFunction(){
            var  taskDone = document.getElementById('taskDone').value;
            var  newForm = document.createElement('form');

            for(var j = 0; j < taskDone ; j++){

                var input1 = document.createElement('input');   

                input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                input1.setAttribute('id', 'time'+i);

                document.body.appendChild(input1);
                newForm.appendChild(input1);
                document.body.appendChild(newForm);
            };
        };
    };
    console.log(myForm);
});
```

so my problem is that in the function when I try to take the value from the generated DOM element it will reset the page what I want to do is to take the number that is going to be placed into the input and make as many new inputs textboxes as it's the number is typed (it takes the number from the generated dom element and creates new dom element)

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: it was supposed to say JavaScript but I guess I didn't have enough space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just doing the wastage of memory you must not place the definition of function inside a loop. You must place it outside the block or a separate definition. You should only call the function inside loop. However, inside your

```
myFunction()
```

you are trying to get the id of an element that doesn't exist as you have created the element with `id = 'taskdone'+i.` So you must also append 'i' inside the myFunction() to get element ids.
But I will suggest you there is a clean way to this task is just pass the element inside myFunction on changing the element value.
Use something like that :

```
 `input0.setAttribute('onchange', 'myFunction(this)');`
```

Then you would no longer require the element id to get its value.
And create your myFunction like this:

```
  function myFunction(element) {
     var id = element.id;
     var taskDone = element.value;
     var i = id.split('taskDone')[1];
     var newForm = document.createElement('form');

     for (var j = 0; j < taskDone; j++) {

         var input1 = document.createElement('input');

         input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
         input1.setAttribute('id', 'time' + i);

         document.body.appendChild(input1);
         newForm.appendChild(input1);
         document.body.appendChild(newForm);
     };
 };
```

See the snippet for more details and help:

```js
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('startSubmit');
  console.log(btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var myForm = document.createElement('form');
    var period  = document.getElementById('period').value;

    for(var i = 0; i < period ; i++){

        var input0 = document.createElement('input');   

        input0.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input0.setAttribute('placeholder', 'The count of tasks');
        input0.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 10px');
        input0.setAttribute('id', 'taskDone'+i);
        input0.setAttribute('onchange', 'myFunction(this)');

        document.body.appendChild(input0);
        myForm.appendChild(input0);
        document.body.appendChild(myForm);

    };
    console.log(myForm);
});
 function myFunction(element){
            var  id = element.id;
   var taskDone = element.value;
   var i = id.split('taskDone')[1];
            var  newForm = document.createElement('form');

            for(var j = 0; j < taskDone ; j++){

                var input1 = document.createElement('input');   

                input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                input1.setAttribute('id', 'time'+i);

                document.body.appendChild(input1);
                newForm.appendChild(input1);
                document.body.appendChild(newForm);
            };
        };
```

```html
<form method="get" action="#" id="startForm">
    <input type="text" name="period" id="period" placeholder="The number of days"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="startSubmit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, man yesterday I've been trying to do this and I spend my whole day working on errors I knew what was wrong but I didn't knew how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function `myFunction()` as `myFunction = function(){..}`
Secondly the id attribute needs to be unique. Hence use

`input0.setAttribute('id', 'taskDone'+i);` to set the id and

```
input0.setAttribute('onchange', 'myFunction("'+i+'")');
```

to call the function.

Similarly access the id as

```
var  taskDone = document.getElementById('taskDone'+i).value;
```

Try the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/djbb79d8/